# Cannot Import arcpy.mapping on ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, nameerror

I can import arcpy and have been using ArcGIS Desktop, but in the tutorial I am following

```
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
NameError: name 'mapping' is not defined
```

This is frustrating because I can access arcpy.mp and other sub modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can import `arcpy.mp` but not `arcpy.mapping` then you are accessing the ArcPy  installed by ArcGIS Pro and not the ArcPy installed by ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop.